# How to make all classes in AppBundle/Service to be used as services?

Tags: symfony, service

I want to automatically add all classes in AppBundle/Service directory as separate services. There's some boiler-plate code, added with the installation of Symfony that should do just that:

```
# makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'
```

The problem is that even though I created a class in `Service` directory I can't find it as a service in `debug:container`. I have no problem to add this service with:

```
app.my_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\MyService
```

But how do I add services automatically, without the need to add each one separately?

Comment: Starting in 3.3, services are defined as being private by default.  To see them use bin/console debug:container --show-private

Comment: Also, if a service is not actually being used (i.e. injected into another service) then Symfony automatically removes them from your container.  Helps to keep the container size done.  So if you still don't see a service then define another class and inject it.

Comment: @Cerad I have tried to get a service using `$this->get('AppBundle\Service\MyService')` but got `You have requested a non-existent service` exception.

Comment: Yep.  And that is because it is private.  Symfony is trying to discourage using the service locator pattern (i.e. $container->get()).  Dependency injection is encouraged.  If you put AppBundle\Service\MyService $myService as a constructor argument then the class will receive it.  If you consider this to be too radical of a change then set public: true in the autowire config section or just manually create your services the old fashion way.  And if you are reading tutorials or what not, make sure they are written for 3.3 or later.

Comment: @Cerad Yeah, I got it now. Thanks for the detailed explanation!